# Preventing SQL injection insert into

Tags: php, sql-injection

I am having trouble inserting data into my database. This is my first time dealing with SQL injection.

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES('name = ?')');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();
```

But that doesn't work. Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors in your code. Try this:

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (:s)');
$stmt->bindParam(':s', $name);
$stmt->execute();
```

If you want to insert and define more values, do it like this:

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES (:s, :email)');
$stmt->bindParam(':s', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->execute();
```

If you're using `mysqli`, your code will look like this:

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (?)');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: That works! But if I want to add more, should I do (:s,:s,:s) ?

Comment: @J.Doe Nope, I'll add an example in my post, hang on :)

Comment: Oh, it's like that! Thank you very much!

Comment: @J.Doe No problemo! :)

Comment: The code in the question is using `mysqli`, not `PDO`. How can this answer work?

Comment: That part of your answer looks a lot like my answer.

Comment: Was just about to ask why I'm getting an error, haha! I'll wait for your answer then :)

Comment: If I want to add more data to the query, can I use (?,?,?) etc?

Comment: @J.Doe Yes. Take a look at the code on http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp under the heading `Prepared Statements in MySQLi'

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `name =` in the SQL, the column name is specified in the list `(name)` after the table name. Just put a `?` where you would normally put the value.

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES(?)');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
$stmt->execute();
```